# Registration page as homepage

Tags: users, user-registration

I would like to have my WordPress registration page / sign up page as my homepage. So that when people go to my root url, the registration page will appear. Any idea how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcode for displaying a registration form and add it to a page or create a custom template with registration page layout.

Once the page will be there, you can choose that page to display in home page from Setting >> Reading  >> Front Page Display ( as in image )

[image]

From this section choose "A static page" and in Front Page, choose the page which have the shortcode or the custom template.

Answer (score 0):

```
Method :1
```

In admin panel In default stetting when use woocommerce.
    **"stetting" => "Reading" => "Front Page Display" => "A static Page" => "Front page"** in select the my account page.

```
Method : 2
```

You can use woocommerce then you can can use this **[woocommerce_my_account]** short code in  "**XYZ**" page. and this page select in **Front page**

[image]